# GitLab Omnibus SSL Vulnerability (Heartbleed)

Tags: security, ssl, gitlab, heartbleed-bug

I installed GitLab 6.6.5 via the [omnibus package](https://www.gitlab.com/downloads) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTE. My question is will the Ubuntu OpenSSL heartbleed update cover the GitLab's installation? The installation has an embedded nginx that is installed. I have enabled SSL via the [GitLab Omnibus Merge Request #66](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests/66).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an embedded NGinX doesn't mean it won't use the `/usr/bin/openssl` installed on your system. (for instance, the [ngx_http_ssl_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) does require openssl)

If that openssl is 1.0.1g or 1.0.2, you won't have any issue.

```
openssl version
```

If not, it is easy enough to recompile it and install it.

To be sure, you can type:

```
ldd /path/to/nginx
```

That will give you the path of the openssl used by the binary `nginx`.
To get the full path, you can then use

```
readlink -f /path/to/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

---

[Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372643/bruno) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945620/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-vulnerability-heartbleed/22945850?noredirect=1#comment35034317_22945850):

> It's probably more about `/lib/*/libssl.so.1.0.0` than `/usr/bin/openssl` (which `ldd` should indicate indeed).
>   **In principle, upgrading to the package with the fix and restarting NGinX should fix the issue**.
>
> Also note that the version numbers in distribution packages (e.g. Ubuntu) don't necessarily match the official version numbers exactly, because they tend to keep the same version number (for the same features), but backport the security patches

---

The [OP crushedGrass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/899357/crushedgrass) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945620/gitlab-omnibus-ssl-vulnerability-heartbleed/22945850#comment35069084_22945850) [Jacob Vosmaer (`jacobvosmaer`)](https://gitlab.com/u/jacobvosmaer)'s [commit "Update omnibus-software (CVE-2014-0160)"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/commit/bcc4ccbfa6c3ce716b3c3ab7317a80c8c352ff96), in  [omnibus-gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab)

> **so all I had to do was run a reconfiguration**.
>   I believe both your and Bruno's feedback is spot on, there are just more dependencies that have to match up.
>   GitLab uses Chef cookbooks to configure the setup and I definitely do not know enough about it to modify it downstream.

Comment: It's probably more about `/lib/*/libssl.so.1.0.0` than `/usr/bin/openssl` (which `ldd` should indicate indeed). In principle, upgrading to the package with the fix *and* restarting NGinX should fix the issue. Also note that the version numbers in distribution packages (e.g. Ubuntu) don't necessarily match the official version numbers exactly, because they tend to keep the same version number (for the same features), but backport the security patches.

Comment: @Bruno Ok. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Tried creating a symbolic link to replace `/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0` with `/lib/*/libssl.so.1.0.0`. After restarting the stack with `gitlab-ctl restart` all I get is a 502 error. I noticed that the GitLab package uses it's own openssl in `/opt/gitlab/bin/`

Comment: @crushedGrass `/lib/*/libssl.so.1.0.0` was a shortcut way to say: "it is somewhere in `/lib`": it is *not* a path for you to copy-paste. If GitLab uses its own openssl, simply type `/opt/gitlab/bin/openssl version` to check its version and see if you are vulnerable to this bug.

Comment: I got it updated last night. Jacob Vosmaer pushed an [update from upstream](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/commit/bcc4ccbfa6c3ce716b3c3ab7317a80c8c352ff96) so all I had to do was run a reconfiguration. I believe both your and Bruno's feedback is spot on, there are just more dependencies that have to match up. GitLab uses Chef cookbooks to configure the setup and I definitely do not know enough about it to modify it downstream. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @crushedGrass Excellent. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Just so it is clear:

```
-> # ldd /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx
...
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fe3cf8f9000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fe3cf520000)
...
```

Gitlab omnibus uses its own bundled OpenSSL. apt-get update **will not** update and protect an install of gitlab omnibus.